# How to map class id to class name in summary plot's legend

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, shap

I fitted a random forest classifier on the iris dataset like so:

```py
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# dividing X, y into train and test data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 0)

model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

Then plot the shap values summary this way:

```py
import shap

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)
```

Output:

[image]

I want to map the `class` ids to the class name in the plot legend:

```py
iris.target_names
array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], dtype='<U10')
```

Such that: `Class 0 -> setosa, Class 1 -> versicolor, Class 2 -> virginica`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `class_names` parameter in the `shap.summary_plot()` function.

Start by getting the class name like this:

```
class_names = iris.target_names
```

and then pass it to the `summary_plot()`

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test, class_names=class_names)
```